# How to skip the first uri segment using htacess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pattern-matching

**Here is the actual uri path:**

```
/css/site.css
```

**I want to map the following uri path to the above one:**

```
/dtkb3im18o/css/site.css
```

In a nutshell, I would like to access `/css/site.css` through `/dtkb3im18o/css/site.css`.

---

**So, I wrote the following rule, but it yields 404 error:**

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+) $1
```

**But, if I use the following rule, it works:**

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+o/(.+) $1
```

---

Basically the difference is, if I use `/` immediately after `+`, it doesn't work. In the above working example, `o` is placed in between them (o is the last character of the first uri segment).

Please note that the first uri segment is a random alphanumeric string.

I'm using the `php:7.3.18-apache` docker image.

---

**Thanks in advance for your kind help. :-)**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+) $1` must work, did you clear the cache before retrying? `^[^/]*/(.+)` should work, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your contribution. I become able to make it working. But how did the `o` thing work?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally discovered the silly mistake:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+) $1
```

Forgot to write the `RewriteCond`.

Still not sure how does the other one work!